# How do I choose a performance program for VCE music performance 3/4?

Tags: performing, cello, education, exam

I have just started year 11 and [VCE music performance units 3 and 4](http://www.vcaa.vic.edu.au/Pages/vce/studies/music/musicperformunits3-4/musicperformunits3-4index.aspx) and was interested in getting ideas for performance programs. I have played cello for 8 years and am currently working on doing my [AmusA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_in_Music,_Australia) at the end of this year. Can anyone provide tips/criteria/advice on how to choose a correct program that follows the guidelines and is playable?